# Read Multiple Files Into List View VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I need to require the user of this program to select two text files from any directory. I then need to display them in a List View, which I have built. File 1 needs to load into the first column and File 2 needs to load into the second. They will correspond to each other.

I currently have the following to allow multiselect

```
OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = True
```

What I am having trouble with is separating these unique files into corresponding columns. For example, the following code very effectively loads the first file's contents into the first column:

```
        Dim fileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

        fileReader = New StreamReader(fileName)

        Do While fileReader.Peek() <> -1
        firstFile = fileReader.ReadLine & vbNewLine
        ListView1.Items.Add(firstFile)

        Loop
```

When I choose the second file, the first file's contents are replaced within the same column by the second file's contents.

I have looked at using an array, but am unsure how to load the unique files into each index.

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: just google for this: Dim subItem = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "text")
ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Insert(i, subItem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = true
```

All selected files are already stored as a collection in `OpenFileDialog1.FileNames`, just loop through all values and put them into the listview

```
ListView1.Items.Clear
Dim file as string
For Each file in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
    ListView1.Item.Add(file)
Next
```

if you want to show the file content in different columns, then you may need to change a little bit of your code

```
    Dim fileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

    fileReader = New StreamReader(fileName)

    Dim FileItem As New ListViewItem
    Do While fileReader.Peek() <> -1
        firstFile = fileReader.ReadLine & vbNewLine

        FileItem .SubItem.Add(firstFile)

    Loop
    ListView1.item.add(Item)
```

However you may need to declare the columns in the ListView1 before adding any item. If not columns define in your ListView1, then it is not possible to show the columns even you have put your file content into the subItem

Comment: This works perfectly for adding the full path of the file, but again, it merely places one on each row in the first column of the list view.

What I am looking for is how to put the file contents into separate columns

Comment: So you want to put the file name into separate columns on one row? I am not sure what do you mean by file contents

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not super clear. File 1 contains a name and File 2 contains an ID Number. By choosing File 1 and File 2, the name should appear in one column and the ID Number in the second column, but both on the same row so they appear to correlate.

Comment: Well Listview is a readonly object, every item is not able to be updated once it is populated. Therefore you can populate the Name into Column 1 but not able to update Column 2 on the same row. There are two methods could solve the problem, the first one is creating a datatable, put all you need from those 2 files into the datatable and bind into the ListView. The second method is still putting the Name into Column 1 from file 1, but when you need to update Column 2, you need to clone the item with column 1 and put column 2 into the subitem, and finally replace the old row with the new item.

Comment: There is one main point you may miss is you need to declare all **columns** you want to see on screen for the ListView1 before you put in any item. Otherwise you won't see any subItems in your ListView

Comment: This ultimately worked, it just took a while for me understand it. Thanks for all the help!